# Parameter value is not recognized, but correctly assigned according to Debugger

Tags: ms-access, parameters, runtime-error

I am struggling with the following problems for hours and I am sure it is just a quick look for one of you experienced guys:

I want to set the variable to the value of a cmb before its value is changed (so I can use the old value to search for the record I want to update), the Debugger shows that the variable itself is getting the right value (= old name as string), but when trying to compare another string to its value it is asking me to enter a parameter value for the variable (although it should have the right value already assigned...)

My Code:
(I cut out the unnecessary parts, when entering the old value manually everything works, so the rest should be fine)

```
Dim CategoryNameBeforeChange As String

CategoryNameBeforeChange = Forms!frmCategory!txtCategoryName.OldValue
'according to the debugger this is assigned correctly 

'update the CategoryTable
strUpdateCatTbl = "UPDATE CategoryTbl " & _
"SET CategoryTbl.CategoryName = Forms!frmCategory!txtCategoryName " & _
"WHERE (CategoryTbl.CategoryName = CategoryNameBeforeChange);"
'CategoryNameBeforeChange is not using the value from above...why?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

answer is here when I shortened the question and asked again it if someone else needs it:

[Correctly assigned parameter valuecan not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949153/correctly-assigned-parameter-valuecan-not-be-used)