# Correctly assigned parameter valuecan not be used

Tags: variables, ms-access, parameters, combobox

I want to get a cmb-value before the entry is changed, by using ".oldValue". The value is correctly assigned (according to debugger), but running the SQL Access is asking for a manual entry. Doing the entry manually works fine, so the remaining code should be fine.

My Code:

```
Dim CategoryNameBeforeChange As String

CategoryNameBeforeChange = Forms!frmCategory!txtCategoryName.OldValue

SQL = "UPDATE CategoryTbl " & _
"SET CategoryTbl.CategoryName = Forms!frmCategory!txtCategoryName " & _
"WHERE (CategoryTbl.CategoryName = CategoryNameBeforeChange);"
```

Any idea what went wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE CategoryTbl " & _
"SET CategoryTbl.CategoryName = Forms!frmCategory!txtCategoryName " & _
"WHERE (CategoryTbl.CategoryName = " & CategoryNameBeforeChange & ");"
```

I suspect that CategoryName is text, in this case it should be

```
SQL = "UPDATE CategoryTbl " & _
"SET CategoryTbl.CategoryName = Forms!frmCategory!txtCategoryName " & _
"WHERE (CategoryTbl.CategoryName = '" & CategoryNameBeforeChange & "');"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sergey S.! The second solution solved it! However can you explain to me why I need to cast it as a string? It was also a string before and it has the same value according to the debugger now and before I changed it?

Comment: You are not casting the value, just SQL syntax requires quotes around strings.

Comment: Ah okay, but why can I normally use it without ' " & ... & " ' then? :)

Comment: You should use quotes if table data type is text. For numbers you don't heed quotes, for dates you need `#` around date.

Comment: thank you! However I often used string without  ' " & ... & " ' and it still worked except for the part I mentioned in my question - probably just VBA-things, who knows